# Experiencing Difficulty in Commiting a Query Via PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm working on a Facebook login script but am having trouble as I don't know if I need beginTransaction(), prepare(), execute() and commit().

Here's my code;

```
<?php
session_start();

$MemberData = $_REQUEST['json'];

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx", 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try { 
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`facebook_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`) VALUES (:faceid, :first_name, :last_name, :email)");

    $sth = $db->prepare($query);

    $sth->execute(array(
    ":faceid" => $MemberData['id'],
    ":first_name" => $MemberData['first_name'],
    ":last_name" => $MemberData['last_name'],
    ":email" => $MemberData['email'])
);
    $Lastid = $db->lastInsertId();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $Lastid;
    $db->commit();  

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //$db->rollBack();
    die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Problem is that this isn't inserting the data into the DB. However, If I set the v alues to strings and comment out most of the code beginning with $sth and set the values to 'string' data the script inserts the data.

Any ideas on what I have wrong here would be most appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump($db->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($sth->ErrorInfo())`?

Comment: And there's no exception at all?

Comment: @andrewsi I dont know... The problem is this page is part of an AJAX call from a facebook login script so I can't really output anything from this page. (Another page calls this script, The data gets inserted, then the visitor is logged in and redirected)

Comment: @Jack Whats odd (to me) is that since this page is run in the BG I never get to see any errors / exceptions

Comment: I'm open for advice from everyone

Comment: @StuartKaufman - you're using $_REQUEST, so you can just add whatever parameters you need to to the query_string, and call the page directly in your browser. Or you can email the errors to yourself, or just write them to a log file somewhere.

Comment: for a SINGLE db operation, there's no need for transactions. you only need a transaction if you're doing multiple db operations that ALL need to succeed. by definition a single query is already an atomic operation. Are you getting actual JSON strings in that $_REQUEST parameter? If so, you need to json_decode() it BEFORE you can use it as an array in php...

Comment: @MarcB Except if the single query is a stored procedure call ;-)

Comment: Also, if you're getting your data from a field called `json`, do you perhaps need to run it through `json_decode` before you can use it?

Comment: @StuartKaufman This may be an ajax request.. But nothing is stopping you from navigating the AJAX Call and debug the script straight from the source.

Comment: @MarcB I'm setting up Transactions so that in the event that 2 people are registering simultaneously, that each will get the proper ID

Comment: @DarylGill Please Do Elaborate on how I can Call and debug this straight from the source

Comment: Believe it or not, I am a very novice webmaster whom has found myself in the deep end QUICKLY

Comment: @stuart: irrelevant. mysql last_insert_id() operates on a per-connection basis. It is not possible for two simultaneous inserts to get their new IDs mixed up. user A cannot get user B's id, or vice versa

Comment: You don't need a transaction to safeguard against two people getting the same id. By the very definition of the auto_increment in MySQL, that scenario simply can't happen (it's a primary key, whose constraint is that it's unique).

Comment: Addition: you are running only 1 query effectively. InnoDB will, by default, wrap it in its own transaction (google innodb autocommit mode). That just means you can prepare the query like @deceze explained in his answer and you don't have to worry about id clashes.

Comment: I am not sure if you posted the table structure already in one of your numerous question on the topic. But nevertheless, it would be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`PDO::query()` fires off a single query; exactly as it sounds, this is not used in conjunctions with other methods. You typically use this for queries which do not take any user-supplied arguments.

`PDO::prepare()` *prepares* a query with placeholders which you later `::execute()`. These two methods go together. You should always use this when using user-supplied values as part of the query.

Transactions are optional for either, but typically useless if you're just firing off one query anyway.

In your case, you'll want to `prepare('INSERT INTO ...')` with placeholders, then `execute()` that prepared statement with the actual data.

---

So, to make that crystal clear:

```
try { 
    $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`facebook_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`) VALUES (:faceid, :first_name, :last_name, :email)");

    $sth->execute(array(
        ":faceid"     => $MemberData['id'],
        ":first_name" => $MemberData['first_name'],
        ":last_name"  => $MemberData['last_name'],
        ":email"      => $MemberData['email']
    ));

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db->lastInsertId();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Basically, OP, you have to remove the `$db->query` function from around your query string. Also if you didnt get an exception or error you may want to turn error reporting on

Comment: @deceze I greatly appreciate your help. I implemented the code exactly as you provided above but for a reason unbeknownst to me the SESSION wont set. However , If I manually set the session by setting = to an existing ID (ie 1, my id) then the session sets and everything seems good but when I use $_SESSION['user_id'] = $db->lastInsertId(); it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Stuart In this case, get set up to debug this script. Nobody can work by stabbing into the dark; you need to check your error logs of both PHP and MySQL (turn query logging on), check the script output, call the script without AJAX or inspect your browser console for the script return values, `var_dump` variables and return values.

Answer (score 0):

`PDOStatement::execute` will return true or false depending on success or failure - just because it doesn't throw an exception, doesn't mean your query worked.

You need to check that the query was successful, and read from `$db->errorInfo()` to find out why it wasn't.

Comment: And if it doesn't? (btw. it doesn't, really)

Comment: "Problem is that this isn't inserting the data into the DB" - so he is probably getting an invalid SQL error, or the database is preventing the insert, neither of which will throw an exception. So he won't know what's wrong unless he reads the `errorInfo()` return.

Comment: There's a proper answer posted, I don't really know why we're wasting time debating here, your answer simply isn't correct but your advice about errorInfo() is ok, you should post it as a comment

Comment: Its not fixing a problem. If it were to do anything, it would help to finding his issue.

Comment: I disagree that the answer previously posted guarantees to solve the problem, it hasn't been accepted as the solution yet. We don't know his database schema, we can't see his error logs, so only he can say which answer fixed his problem.

Comment: @Ascherer does that mean only answers that include code are valid?

Comment: no, answers that actually answer the question, not comments that provide insight into maybe finding errors. And if you read the comments in the other answer, the answer solved the db writing issue

Answer (score 0):

What it have to be

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx", 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = "INSERT INTO subscribers (facebook_id,first_name,last_name,email) 
             VALUES (:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email)";
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($_REQUEST['json']);

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $db->lastInsertId();
```

without all the useless code

if you're calling this code via AJAX call, you have to check for for possible errors somehow - either in Firebug console or in web-server logs.

By the way. I am not sure if you posted the table structure already in one of your numerous question on the topic. But nevertheless, it would be a good idea anyway. It seems that it could be quite possible that your table doesn't have na auto_increment attribute on id